# Is it necessary to duplicate user credentials when using proxysql in front of a database cluster?

Tags: mysql, percona-xtradb-cluster, proxysql

I've set up a Percona Xtradb Cluster with 5 nodes on a network that also has a ProxySQL server. I have ProxySQL working, I can log in to the admin interface on port 6032 and administer it and I can also log in through port 6033, connecting to the cluster.

The problem (at least as I see it) is that I am only able to get through the proxy to the cluster (port 6033) by duplicating the user/pass for the cluster at the proxysql level.

I would have thought that there would be some way to have the credentials simply pass through the proxy to the cluster or at least some other way to not have to store the user/pass in two points for these connections.

Is this all exactly by design and I'm just hoping for something that doesn't exist because of good reasons like security/practices or is there some way to improve this setup to not have to tell ProxySQL about every database user I ever need to access the cluster databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short - yes. it's simply the way ProxySQL handles queries.

Also,if security is one of your concerns you may think of password hashing on ProxySQL side.
Here's the official doc: [Password management](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/Password-management) on how to configure.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wiki](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/Password-management#mysql-passwords-in-proxysql):

> Because ProxySQL performs routing based on traffic, when a client
>   connects it cannot yet identify a destination HG, therefore ProxySQL
>   needs to authenticate the client. For this reason, it needs to have
>   some information related to the password of the user: enough
>   information to allow the authentication.